# Absolute file path to server path

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and am having an issue:
CodeIgniter's `base_url()` function resolves site name root folder e.g `http://localhost/sitename`. I have a third-party library installed outside the application folder. This library requires absolute path to a file e.g. `C:\xampp\sitename\file.ext`. I want this to resolve to the server paths e.g. `base_url().file.ext` (`http://localhost/sitename/file.ext`). How can i achieve that. Thank you.

Comment: `<?php echo base_url();?>/file.ext`

Comment: @Yadhu Babu this is going to be like http://localhost/sitename/file.ext but i want it http:\\localhost\sitename\file.ext

Comment: In your question you are referencing it with forward slashes, in your comment it is with backslashes? Which one is it? Also you say base_url() resolves to http://localhost/sitename, but in your comment you reference it as localhost/sitename/file.ext? How is Yadhu's comment not correct? What is it exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Absolute path and URL are two different things. Do you want `FCPATH` maybe ([docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html?highlight=fcpath)) that is actually file system path to the application's root directory?

Comment: @Tpojka Yeah that's what i really wanted. Thank you